# Prevent MVC from binding default datatype values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The model I have has an integer property. Using the basic `@Html.EditorFor` in the view generated a textbox. When the page loads for the first time, the value `0` is entered by default, probably because `0` is the default value of a instantiated integer. How can I prevent MVC from binding the `0`?

Using weakly typed properties is not the right solution, neither is choosing `nullable` datatypes. The same is true for `enums`: The first option ends up being selected by default.

**Edit for clarification:**

The reason is purely cosmetic. It makes no sense to have a 0 in a house number field, it's never correct and will have to be removed by generally all users. It also prevents the required field validation from executing.

Comment: Why do you want to stop it from binding the 0? You can't put a null value in an `int` so logically there's nothing you can display apart from 0 when the int has a default value. You could create your own textbox template which showed blank when the value was zero. Can you explain more about the intended usage and the reason you can't use nullable data types?

Comment: Your choice of a int value for the house number is wrong. Many civic address has letter in their house number. You see that often in a multigeneration or bachelor house where the house number will be 123 and 123A.

Comment: Agreed - and there are plenty of addresses where the premises may not have a number at all - in the UK it is not uncommon for a house to have a name instead of a number, which is perfectly valid

Comment: The 'suffix' is stored in a separate property and field in the database. It has it's own textbox. The house number itself can only contain numbers 1 to (in theory) 19999.

Comment: As James S has answered, it's nullable data types you want - since to have a 'required' field not be valid, it needs to have a non-valid value. Since 0 is a valid value for an integer the validation has run and the value is considered correct by the validation framework. I'd also have to agree with Pierre's comment above, whilst in 99% of situations you have a number, you occasionally have a suffix (such as a letter) and sometimes have a property with no number at all. My office address has no number, the building is simply called "Riverside". A string would be the best choice here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nullable datatypes is exactly the right solution.

You should be using a Model with a `Nullable<int>` instead of an int property.
If that property is decorated with the `[Required]` attribute (from the  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace) then the user will still be forced to enter a value.

Remember the model you are binding should really be a ViewModel - ie a model with properties that are relevant for passing data to and from the View. This may be (and often is) a different model from what is being stored in the database (or business model / Entity Framework model etc)!